# pylzma stream (de)compression buffer size

Tags: python, lzma

There's an example usage of stream (de)compression at github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/doc/usage.txt, however, it always reads by 1 byte, which, obviously, can get relatively slow.

However, reading by some larger size (e.g. 65k) and doing `obj.decompress()` as-is becomes problematic on large files as, apparently, as a result pylzma stores most of the data internally and then decompresses it all on `obj.flush()`.

The `decompress` method has a `bufsize` parameter (which by default seems to be 128k). Setting it to over 30*read_size (30 being approximate compression ratio) makes decompression work as intended (and quite fast); however, this will obviously break on, for example, several gigabytes of zero bytes (as compression ratio will be much higher).

Thus, the question: how to properly (de)compress a file with pylzma (using an appropriate buffer size for speed)?